# How can I return the text of a button clicked using execute_script?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium

How can I get the text of a button clicked and return it to python? The button is selected using a mouse-click generated by the user in the Selenium WebDriver browser.

I'm trying to do as follows:

```
x=driver.execute_script("$(document).click(function(event){var text= $(event.target).text(); return text})")
```

but when I print the contents of `x` it returns None. When I try to use an alert to display the contents of `text`, it returns the correct contents but I want to return it in Python.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Find button locator and get its text. Why are you using execute_script?

Comment: The aim of the task is to perform a mouse click and get the details of the relevant element.  I'm accessing the elements using a mouse click and I'm only using Selenium to get the details.

Comment: You can't return values which happen during a random time.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on the button,
You can extract the text of the button only if it's still available in the dom visible, else you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Identify element
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id")

# Click element
element.click()

# Get text
print("Text is: " + element.text)

# Or
print("Text is: " + element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```